# Programmatically enter text into input and refresh web page accordingly--iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, input, uiwebview, enter

I would like to create an app that requests the user for something they would like to search on a website, say cnn.com

[On CNN's site](http://www.cnn.com), there is a an input box that one can enter text and then click search. Instead of loading the webpage and filling that box and then clicking search, I would like the user to enter that information in the app, and by clicking search through the app, it will load the results in a `UIWebView`.

To summarize, this app will get the text that the user wants to search, fill it into the input value in the webpage, and finally retrieve the URL that is the product of searching.

What is the process I will need to go through to accomplish this? Any help would be GREAT!!! Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Using the actual user frontend of a website as an interface for your software is never a good idea unless its not possible otherwise (means: don't try to fill the input boxes and send the HTML form as a user would do).
The easiest way you could accomplish a page of results is by finding out how the search page actually queries the page of results.

- If theres a simple HTML form using the HTTP POST method on the search page, you could use its target URL and the parameters and create your own HTTP-POST-Request for your search. The reply to this request should be exactly the same as when using the search form on the website.
- If the results page is loaded via a GET request, you could simply build a request URL with your own search parameter and call the results page with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to observe the URL query strings. Let's take the CNN for example.

- when you enter the site, the url is: http://edition.cnn.com/
- when you enter some text(i.e."us economy") to the search box and hit
  the enter the URL will be:
  http://edition.cnn.com**/search/?query=us+economy**&x=36&y=14&primaryType=mixed&sortBy=relevance&intl=true

you see the searched text being held in URL ?
So the only thing you need to do in order to trigger your own search so to compose a correct url and display it (in webview or iframe etc.).